# Mongodb Find() Query from Powershell

Tags: json, mongodb, powershell

For the following `Json` file, I have a `mongodb` query to select `"Car"` part of document only:

```
db.collection.find({_item:"Home"}, {"Car":1, "_id":0})
```

How do I write this query in `Powershell`?

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "_item": "Home",
   "Car": [
    {"name": "BMW", "model": "series 3"},
    {"name": "Audi", "model": "A4"}
   ],
   "Fruit": [
    {"name": "Banana", "color": "Yellow"},
    {"name": "Apple", "color": "Red"}
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$databaseName = "database"
$collectionName = "collection"
$client = New-Object -TypeName MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient -ArgumentList "mongodb://localhost:27017"
$server = $client.GetServer()
$database = $server.GetDatabase($databaseName)
$collection = $database.GetCollection($collectionName)

$query = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ("_item","HOME")
$results = $collection.Find($query).SetFields(Fields.Exclude("_id").Include("Car"))
```

Comment: Excellent. I get an error says Missing ')' on SetFields function. Do you get an error?

Comment: add MongoDB.Driver.Builders. before Fileds and see what happens

Comment: Same result. Is this driver for powershell 3.0+ ? I am using 2.0

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$results = $collection.Find($query).SetFields( [MongoDB.Driver.Builders.fields]::Exclude("_id").include("Car"))
```